# Executing Python Script with PHP Variables

Tags: php, python, forms, variables, python-2.7

I am writing a simple application that uses information from a form, passes it through $_POST to a PHP script that executes a python script and outputs the results. The problem I am having is that my python script is not actually running with the arguments being passed in.

process3.php file:

```
<?php
     $start_word = $_POST['start'];
     $end_word = $_POST['end'];
     echo "Start word: ". $start_word . "<br />";
     echo "End word: ". $end_word . "<br />";
     echo "Results from wordgame.py...";
     echo "</br>";
     $output = passthru('python wordgame2.py $start_word $end_word');
     echo $output;
?>
```

Output:

```
Start word: dog
End word: cat
Results from wordgame.py...
Number of arguments: 1 arguments. Argument List: ['wordgame2.py']
```

At the top of my wordgame2.py, I have the following (for debugging purposes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Why isn't the number of arguments being passed = 3? 
(Yes, my form does send the data correctly.)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I might add that it does run when I explicitly tell it the start and end word... something like this:

```
$output = passthru('python wordgame2.py cat dog');
echo $output
```

Comment: What do you see when you `echo 'python wordgame2.py $start_word $end_word'` in your php file?

Comment: After adding that line, it now outputs:
    Start word: dog
    End word: cat
    Results from wordgame.py...
    python wordgame2.py dog cat
Number of arguments: 1 arguments. Argument List: ['wordgame2.py']

Comment: I think the mistake lies in `$output = passthru('python wordgame2.py $start_word $end_word');` Try this `$output = passthru('python wordgame2.py '.$start_word." ".$end_word);` Maybe, python is rejecting the arguments due to $ keyword (or maybe $ is invoking the shell for variable repplacement)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update -**

Now that I am aware of PHP, the mistake lies in using the single-quotes `'`. In PHP, single quoted strings are considered literals, PHP does not evaluate the content inside it. However, double quoted `"` strings are evaluated and would work as you are expecting them to. This is beautifully summarized in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/2689986). In our case,

```
$output = passthru("python wordgame2.py $start_word $end_word");
```

would work, but the following won't -

```
$output = passthru('python wordgame2.py $start_word $end_word');
```

**Original answer -**

I think the mistake lies in

```
$output = passthru("python wordgame2.py $start_word $end_word");
```

Try this

```
$output = passthru("python wordgame2.py ".$start_word." ".$end_word);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious solution be using " instead of '? No need to concatenate when " does variable interpolation.

Comment: Hmm...am not much familiar with php (none at all), so only my answer begins with *I think...*

Comment: Also, probably good to use `escapeshellarg()` on the two arguments passed in when concatenating.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your contributions. I have figured out my problem with this simple fix:

```
$command = 'python wordgame2.py ' . $start_word . ' ' . $end_word;
$output = passthru($command);
```

In order for passthru to properly handle the php variables, it needs to be concatenated into the string before executing.

Comment: Instead of posting your answer, which is ashish's answer, please accept his answer.

Comment: I had posted this before I saw his answer. Please look at the time stamp.

Comment: Actually, I answered 7 seconds before :) The downvote was unnecessary/unverified.

Answer (score 0):

well if I understood you want pass a big amount of text like content of something, so  the right way is;

$output = passthru("python wordgame2.py ".json_encode($end_word)." ".json_encode($start_word));