# how to run a python file using exec() function in php

Tags: python, php

this my php form (form1.php)

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="process1.php" method="post">
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"  required ><br><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass"  required ><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
        <html>
    <body>
```

process.php

```
    <?php $email = $_POST["email"]; ?>
    <?php $pass  = $_POST["pass"]; ?>
    
    
    <?php echo($email) ?>    <br>
    <?php echo($pass) ?>   <br>
```

i want to use $email , $pass variable values from php.
And i want to send data from the varibles to my salesforce account using python to a custom object...

python file

```
import requests
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username="USER", password= "PWD",security_token="" )
print(sf)
params = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "X0000XXXX", 
    "client_secret": "XX00000X",
    "username": "XXX0XX", 
    "password": "XX0XX"
}

dataset = [{'email__c':'$email(this should be the variable from php)', 'password__c': '$pass (this should be the variable from php) '}]
sf.bulk.aryan__c.insert(dataset,batch_size=1,use_serial=True)
```

Comment: can you show an example of what you intend to do in python?

Comment: i have edited my question see......

Comment: tell the answere pls,
i will change the password and thanks for informing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make your python file CLI compatible. You need to [catch the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments). The easiest way to do it would be something like this:

```
import sys

def myFunc(user, pwd):
    print(user,pwd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        user = sys.argv[1]
        pwd = sys.argv[2]
        myFunc(user, pwd)
```

Also have a look at [argparse](https://realpython.com/command-line-interfaces-python-argparse/) and [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/).

Then you can [call the script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781768/executing-python-script-with-php-variables/19781913) and provide the credentials. There are actually several ways to do it. While your wish `exec` will not return the output of the python script

[passthru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781768/executing-python-script-with-php-variables/19781913)

```
$output = passthru("python3 myScript.py $user $pwd");
```

[shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
$prog = 'python3 myScript.py '.$user.' '.$pwd;
$output = shell_exec($prog);
```

[exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)

```
exec("python3 myScript.py $user $pwd");
```